# How to collect data from variable to Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Here is my code

```
for (int j = 0; j < noofyears.length; j++) {
    // Formula To calculate D16         
    double D16 = (B8 * ((dp - 1) / B13));
    System.out.println("D16:" + D16);
}
```

Here I am doing some mathematical calculation on single variable. How can I collect the D16 all the data to array

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Be more specific.

Comment: what is `dp`, `B8`, `B13` and `j` here? You copy it from excel?

Comment: I am getting results perfectly D16:Value 1,D16:Value2,D16:Value3....... till for loop ends ,but I want to store all the data ie Vale1,Value2..... to array. How can I implement this?

Comment: @AmeetM but all `D16` values are the same

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. At the end of the loop resultArray will have your desired values.

```
    double[] resultArray = new double[noofyears.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < noofyears.length; j++) {
        // Formula To calculate D16         
        double D16 = (B8 * ((dp - 1) / B13));
        resultArray[j] = D16;
        System.out.println("D16:" + D16);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ameet M : assigning to an array is just like assigning to a variable. Only thing is that you need to index your array and then be sure about its range to avoid errors. For all practical purposes Johnson Abraham has answered for what you are looking for.

You can use java collections too store list of values as :

```
List<Double> d16List = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 0; j < noofyears.length; j++) {
        // Formula To calculate D16         
        double D16 = (B8 * ((dp - 1) / B13));
        d16List.add(D16);
        System.out.println("D16:" + D16);
}
```

And then use the `d16List` instead of an array.